# Precompiled Header Syntax

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I recently discovered the concept of using a precompiled header within a large project, to speed up compile time for those system headers that do not change.

I am now attempting to add to my own project, my question, is this the correct syntax ? or is there something more i have to add, for it to be marked and recognized as a pch.h ?  thanks

```
#ifndef PCH_H_INCLUDED
#define PCH_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <strstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

#endif // PCH_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Assuming you are talking about Visual Studio, then you can put what you like in your PCH, it's how you structure your project and what compiler options you use that counts.

Comment: "pch.h" is just default name used for precompiled header in visual studio. Header files are not "marked and recognized" as precompiled headers just because they have some particular names or special content. You actually need to specify header file to be used as a precompiled header among compiler arguments. Also it would be a good idea to place SFML headers prior to standard library headers when including them.

Comment: Im using the latest code blocks and the default compiler it comes with. clicking on the .h file then property ive checked the file to be compiled and unchecked to be linked, as i read somewhere must be done, if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the Visual Studio responces, but in codeblocks a pch is just a regular header file and requires to be marked as a pch.

Comment: How to use precompiled headers with CodeBlocks is clearly explained by
[the documentation](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Precompiled_headers).
If you do not understand something about it or cannot make it work, please
edit your question to tell us the problem.